# Making the postgreSQL/SQL Alchemy orm select faster

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a table with a large number of rows ( ~ 1 million ) and when I use the following select query It takes avg of .002 seconds to get the result, I have to loop through this records, so I need this to be faster, I am using an SQLAlchemy ORM to execute queries

```
 MaxSeq = 10 #MaxSeq  can change 
 config.session.query(OTableConsignList.A).filter(
                    OTableConsignList.B== 'SOMEID',
                    OTableConsignList.A!= 'SOMETHING' ,
                    OTableConsignList.A!=  'SOMETHING_ELSE', or_(OTableConsignList.C< MaxSeq ,
                                                               MaxSeq == 0))
```

I have created an index as follows

```
CREATE INDEX consign_list_index ON tbl_consign_list("A","B","C")
```

Now any other suggestions to improve the speed?

Comment: Instead of running a query like this for each ID of interest, I suggest you try to query all of the IDs you care about at the same time. That's generally much more efficient.

Comment: Yea, I will try that

Comment: I think that indexes cannot be used to satisfy not equals predicates, so having `"A"` as the first column of the index might not be a good idea. Instead it looks like just `("B", "C")` would be a better choise. Remember to use `EXPLAIN` to check if your indexes are being used, and also that sometimes a seq scan is faster. Now, the question itself is a bit unclear. You say that the query executes in 2 ms, but still require it to be faster? That's a quite tight requirement.